# how to use an autoloader in php

Tags: php, git

I'm new to PHP and not really familiar with using git.

I got this library:

https://github.com/CKOTech/checkout-php-library

and I wanna run the sample code here:

https://github.com/CKOTech/checkout-php-library/wiki/Tokens

I know the code may not work perfectly for you cuz you would need a secret key from the provider, however, I don't need general errors like " cannot find class ApiClient"

what I did is simply including the autoloader in my index.php file, is that all what I have to do to use an Autoloader? does it have to do anything with composer.json?

Thanks a ton for the help in advance.

Autoloader.php:

```
<?php
function autoload($className)
{

    $baseDir = __DIR__;
    $realClassName = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $realClassName = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$realClassName );
    $fileName  = '';
    $includePaths = $baseDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$realClassName. '.php';

    if ( $file = stream_resolve_include_path($includePaths) ) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
        }

    }elseif(preg_match('/^\\\?test/', $className)) {
        $fileName = preg_replace('/^\\\?test\\\/', '', $fileName);
        $fileName = 'test' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . $fileName;
        include $fileName;

    } else {
        $classNameArray = explode('_', $className);
        $includePath = get_include_path();
        set_include_path($includePath);

        if (!empty($classNameArray) && sizeof($classNameArray) > 1) {

            if (!class_exists('com\checkout\packages\Autoloader')) {
                include 'com'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'checkout'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'packages'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Autoloader.php';
            }
         }
    }

}


spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an autoloader to make your life measurably better:

1. Use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)/[PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).
2. Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).

So let's say I'm working on project foo, within my working directory [let's just say it's `/`] I make a folder named `/src/` and inside is `/src/FooClient.php`. It contains:

```
<?php
namespace sammitch\foo;

class FooClient {}
```

While in `/` I run `composer init` and accept all of the defaults, because typing out the simple JSON config file that that generates is tedious. Now I have a `composer.json` that looks like:

```
{
    "name": "Sammitch/foo",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sammitch",
            "email": "sammitch@sam.mitch"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}
```

All we need to do now is add a section to the end:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "sammitch\\foo\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Now to make Composer do it's magic and make the autoloader just run `composer dumpautoload`. When this runs Composer will create the `/vendor/` folder and the autoloader.

Now all we need to do is:

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use \sammitch\foo\Client as FooClient()

$c = new FooClient();
```

Now not only do you have a top-tier autoloader, but you're also set up to start using Composer packages and leveraging all that good stuff from [Packagist](https://packagist.org/).